# How to debug Django 1.8 AppConfig?

Tags: django, django-registration, django-signals, django-logging

I'm using Django 1.8.

I'm trying to wire up the [django-registration user_registration signal](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#registration.signals.user_registered).

To wire up [a signal](http://chriskief.com/2014/02/28/django-1-7-signals-appconfig/), this post is pretty explicit: use [AppConfig.ready()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready).  I think I have it wired up correctly, but clearly I don't, because it's not working.  So, to see what happened, I deliberately misspelled the name of the config class in my registrationapp/__init__.py:

```
default_app_config = 'registrationapp.apps.RegistrationAppConfgOOPS'
```

I don't see any error message, or any message.

How do I tell if registrationapp/__init__.py is even being loaded, and if the right app config is being created and loaded?

By the way, I set up console logging **exactly** as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#examples), but it doesn't log much to the console, not sure why.  (It does log the GET requests, but they look to be different logging.)

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How do I tell if `registrationapp/__init__.py` is even being loaded?*

A very simple way would be putting a top-level `print()` in it. If it's loaded, you will see the output.

*...and if the right app config is being created and loaded?*

Same thing, put a `print()` in your app config file.

I just tried using a bogus name for `default_app_config` in my project and Django raised an `AttributeError`, so I think that indeed your app is not being found.

Regarding logging, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples) says this:

> By default, this config only sends messages of level INFO or higher to the console. Django does not log many such messages. Set the environment variable DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG to see all of Django’s debug logging which is very verbose as it includes all database queries.

So try using `os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')` instead.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I was using registrationapp to customize the django-registration-redux package (the "registration" app), but I was not including registrationapp in INSTALLED_APPS. So, I included it and all is well.